# CoreData+Multithreading Pattern. Am I Doing it Right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, core-data

I write an iOS application that uses Core Data to store its stuff. The data stored in managed objects and updated in separate threads (I'm using GCD). An Apple suggests two ways in its `Core Data Programming Guide` a pattern to adopt Core Data to be used in multithreading environment:

1. Create a separate managed object context for each thread and share a single persistent store coordinator.
   This is the typically-recommended approach.
2. Create a separate managed object context and persistent store coordinator for each thread.
   This approach provides for greater concurrency at the expense of greater complexity (particularly if you need to communicate changes between different contexts) and increased memory usage.

So I choosed the first one.
I have an `Database` class that manages all the Core Data related stuff.

```c
// Database.h

#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Database : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *model;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *context;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator;

+ (Database *)sharedInstance;

@end


// Database.m

#import "Database.h"

static NSManagedObjectModel *sharedModel;
static NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *sharedCoordinator;

static NSMutableDictionary *contexts;

@implementation Database

+ (NSMutableDictionary *)contextsDictionary
{
    if (!contexts) {
        contexts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return contexts;
}

+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)contextForThread:(NSThread *)thread
{
    id threadKey = @(thread.hash);
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [Database contextsDictionary][threadKey];
    if (!context) {
        context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        context.persistentStoreCoordinator = sharedCoordinator;
        contexts[threadKey] = context;
        [context release];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:[Database class]
                                                 selector:@selector(threadWillExit:)
                                                     name:NSThreadWillExitNotification
                                                   object:thread];
    }
    return context;
}

+ (void)threadWillExit:(NSThread *)thread
{
    id threadKey = @(thread.hash);
    [contexts removeObjectForKey:threadKey];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:[Database class]
                                                    name:NSThreadWillExitNotification
                                                  object:thread];
}

+ (Database *)sharedInstance
{
    static Database *shared;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        shared = [[Database alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        sharedModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];
        sharedCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:sharedModel];

        NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyModelFile"]];
        NSError *error = nil;
        [sharedCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSBinaryStoreType
                                        configuration:nil
                                                  URL:storeUrl
                                              options:nil
                                                error:&error];
        NSAssert(!error, @"Initialization error %@", error);
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)model
{
    return sharedModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    return sharedCoordinator;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    return [Database contextForThread:[NSThread currentThread]];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [sharedModel release];
    [sharedCoordinator release];
    [contexts release];

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

So I am curious, am I doing it right? Are there any problems in my code? Are there any patterns that I can use here?

Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at the ["Core Data Release Notes for OS X v10.7 and iOS 5.0"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html). Managed object contexts using the new concurrency types NSMainQueueConcurrencyType and NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType automatically manage their queues (and threads) and are much easier to use. Unfortunately, this is not yet mentioned in the "Core Data Programming Guide".

Comment: This is a great article about Core Data and concurrency: http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html

Comment: Well, the articles you both suggested was really helpful, and now all the stuff can be done much easier! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The described multithreading pattern is not relevant now because core data have a builtin concurrency support. As mentioned in articles [Core Data Release Notes for OS X v10.7 and iOS 5.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html) and [Common Background Practices](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html) a moc may be configured with proper concurrency type either `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` or `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`. Then each operation with managed object context may be performed in block passed to `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` methods and let the core data internals to handle all concurrency stuff.